# Problema com filtro de data no C# (MongoDB)

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-csharp

Estou tentando fazer um filtro entre datas no C# em uma tabela que esta no MongoDB. Os resultados esperados devem estar entre os dias 19/11/2020 e 20/11/2020.

Este é meu código no C#:

```
collection.Find<Admissao>(x => x.created_in >= startDate && x.created_in <= endDate.AddDays(1));
```

O código me retorna 35 registros.

Se eu executar o mesmo filtro direto no MongoDB, dessa forma:

```
db.getCollection('ContratosAdmissao').find({"created_in":{$gte:new ISODate("2020-11-19T00:00:00.000Z"),$lte:new ISODate("2020-11-21T00:00:00.000Z")}})
```

Me retorna 41 registros.

Não estou entendendo porque no C# não retorna a mesma quantidade, notei que esses 6 registros de diferença possui o horário entre 00:00:00 (meia noite) e 02:00:00 (duas horas).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu alterar o horário dessas datas no MongoDB para 03:00:00, elas passam a ser filtradas no C#.

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que analisar que o MongoDB está com o DateTime com UTC-0 provavelmente quando esse registro vem para sua aplicação ele está vindo com UTC-3 que é o UTC do Brasil.

Então na verdade esses registro no MongoDB quando chega no C# está subtraindo 3 horas portanto eles deixam de ser do Dia 19 e passam a ser do Dia 18. Isso responderia porque quando o tempo é maior que 3 horas ele consegue filtrar.

Comment: Muito provável que o problema é este mesmo. Porém, acho que seria uma boa ideia [edit] a resposta e adicionar opções para resolvê-lo.

Comment: Então é um pouco complicado escrever uma solução, por que o problema em si está bem abstrato. Por exemplo ele pode ter mandado a data como 2020-11-18 21:00:00 porem no Mongo foi salvo como UTC-0 portanto ele definiu a hora para 2020-11-19 00:00:00 então a consulta dele no C# não está errada, seria interessante entender esse ponto.